# how to update variables defined in batch file

Tags: file, batch-file

Below is code from my batch file:

```
@echo off & setlocal
set ver1="doc pic\ABC\" 
set ver2="C:\Users\elmo\Desktop\error4.png"
E:
cd %ver1%
copy %ver2%
```

The issue is I am not getting any way to update these variables from my program; is there any way trick I can do so?

Comment: What program?  What exactly are you trying to do?  Also, `@echa off`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables for a process are populated at process start from the parent process. Afterwards it is not possible to change or add variables in a running process.

So if you have your batch file and run another program from it and then try changing environment variables for the batch file from that program, that is impossible.

If you are trying the other way around – that is, start the batch file from another program, then you can influence the batch file's environment variables by setting them first in your program.

EDIT: As you said you have a text file that contains the information you need. The easiest way would be if that text file takes the appearance of another batch file, e.g.:

```
set ver1=foo
set ver2=bar
```

in which case you could just “include” it with

```
call foobar.cmd
```

If it looks like this instead:

```
ver1=foo
ver2=bar
```

you can make it work similarly by parsing it with `for /f` and just running a `set` command for each line:

```
for /f "delims=" %%L in (foobar.txt) do set "%%L"
```

If it just looks like this:

```
foo
bar
```

then a little more work is needed (because you just implicitly know that the first line is `ver1` and the second `ver2`):

```
for /f "delims=" %%L in (foobar.txt) do (
  if not defined ver1 (
    set "ver1=%%L"
  ) else if not defined ver2 (
    set "ver2=%%L"
  )
)
```

Now, this works if `ver1` and `ver2` are not defined prior to parsing that text file. If you merely need to update their values it gets messier:

```
for /f "delims=" %%L in (foobar.txt) do (
  if not defined ver1updated (
    set "ver1=%%L"
    set ver1updated=1
  ) else if not defined ver2updated (
    set "ver2=%%L"
    set ver2updated=1
  )
)
set ver1updated=
set ver2updated=
```

Although in your specific case you can take advantage of that there are two ways of reading a file into a variable and they differ in how they handle multiple lines:

```
set /p ver1=<foobar.txt
for /f "delims=" %%L in (foobar.txt) do set ver2=%%L
```

The first one will just store the very first line of the file, while the second approach will update the variable for every line in the file, leaving `ver2` at the value of the *last* line. Since there are only two lines to begin with that's also an option of separating them. But when writing batch files I usually try not to mix idioms or at least provide a comment to explain.

As you can see, it can get a little complex. In general for such questions it would help if you stated exactly what format you *can* generate (if there are restrictions) or what exactly are your input and output formats (you can edit your question too :-)).

Comment: Thanks Joey for your response. let me make tell you some more things. I am not using any .NET technology to run this batch file, I am using another language called sanscript which is similar as VB6 syntax. It has a function by using which I can run batch file just like running on RUN command.. I means If I open RUN prompt and write the batch file name with full path and enter then it will do the work, I want to know can we pass parameters to batch file while running it like it?

Comment: If you are running external programs from the batch file you can parse their output. Or you could store a file in a known location and have the batch file read it. All options are a little icky and it depends a little on what you can (or are willing) to do and how reliable it needs to be.

Comment: I have created text file having both parameters, this text file will be created from my program and each time will have new/different values, now my only concern is to read that two lines from that text file in my batch file and update the ver1 and ver2 values. Is it possible?

Comment: wow. a great deal of detail. I will try your method and let you know if it worked or not. till then wait. I must say that thank you. next time I will try to provide as much information as I can.. thanks for the tip :) (Y)

Comment: thank you Joey! with your help and explanation I have accomplished something which seems impossible to me. That's some thing great for the application I am working for.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `set /P` option, you can set the variable to be the result of a prompt.

```
set /P ver1=Enter path:
```

This would allow(force) the user to input the variable.  Specifically, the user would be prompted

```
Enter path:
```

Then whatever they typed after would be placed into ver1.

Note, in this example, the user would type something with a space in it.  You would be safer putting `%ver1` in speech marks so it was `"%ver1"`.

---

To load from an external file, try `set /P ver1= <file.txt`.  You may want to check if the file exists with `if exist file.txt (set /P ver1= <file.txt)`

If you want to allow the user to change the file before editing it, simple call a `pause` before hand and prompt the user to change the text files required.

For example, if you want a user to see what paths are set so they can change them first, you can try...

```
@echo off
echo "Destination path (ver1.txt): " <ver1.txt
echo "Source path (ver2.txt): " <ver2.txt
echo "Please change the values in the text files as required."
pause
set /P ver1= <ver1.txt
set /P ver2= <ver2.txt
```

It's been a while since I actually did something like this, so I may need to check up on it, but I believe this should work.

Comment: @elmo If it's right, feel free to tick it as the right answer.  If not, provide more info and I can maybe help more.

Comment: Splatter it's a good information, but in my case I can not force user to enter value. I have these values in a  text file can I read directly from text file?